# How to retrieve search results of specific query of Amazon with python requests?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python requests,

how can I simply submit a GET request to the search box on Amazon's homepage and get response with Python?

It appears that I can use Amazon simple product api, but the response is wrapped up.

Thanks!

Comment: use the api ... it will save you alot of headaches

Comment: Could you please show us what you've tried per [StackOverflow's posting guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/about)?

Comment: However, a quick search on amazon reveals a target url something like `http://www.amazon.com/s/field-keywords=MYQUERYHERE`...

Comment: I will post what I tried later... But interestingly, if you search in the search box with "Harry Potter", a long url will be generated "http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=harry+potter&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Aharry+potter", but if I type in "http://www.amazon.com/s/field-keywords=harry%20potter" in the browser, it generates the same page.